# Returning text into an input text box from another page on my domain using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to return the text from another page on my domain into an input text box. I can return the text inside a div (DivThisPage) but can't seem to get the text from the div I've loaded in to the text input field (txtValue).

```
function getValue() {
  $("#DivThisPage").load("http://another-page-on-my-site #DivTheOtherPage"); //This is working and I see "test" on this page. 
  var myVal = $('#DivThisPage').val(); //I've tried both DivThisPage and DivTheOtherPage but get nothing
  $("#txtValue").val(myVal);
}
```

Here is the HTML on this page:

```
<button onclick="getValue()">Get Value</button>
<div id="DivThisPage"></div>
<input type="text" id="txtValue" name="txtValue" />
```

The html from another page on my site:

```
<div id="DivTheOtherPage">test</div>
```

However, when I inspect the elements on the page after executing I see:

```
<div id="DivThisPage">
<div id="DivTheOtherPage">test</div>
</div>
```

But when I debug the script myVal is always null.

Comment: `div` elements don't have a `value`. Do you instead mean that you want to put the *text* from the div you load in to the `#txtValue` input? Also note that you'll need to use the callback argument of `load()` as the AJAX call to get the data is asynchronous

Comment: Use `text()` or `html()` for the `div`, not value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly, `div` elements do not have a `value` attribute so the `val()` method doesn't work for them. Assuming from the context of the question you want to get the text within the element, use `html()` or `text()`.

Secondly, the AJAX call used by `load()` under the hood is asynchronous. This means that you will need to use the callback argument in order to read the data from the DOM *after* it has been updated.

```html
<button>Get Value</button>
<div id="DivThisPage"></div>
<input type="text" id="txtValue" name="txtValue" />
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $("#DivThisPage").load("/relative-path #DivTheOtherPage", function() {
      var myVal = $('#DivTheOtherPage').text();
      $("#txtValue").val(myVal);
    }); 
  });
});
```

Also note that use of an unobtrusive event handler here. Inline event attribute are now considered bad practice (as they tie the HTML and JS logic too tightly) and should be avoided where possible.

In addition, if you're making a call to a location on your own site, use a relative link.

Answer (score 1):

Uses this:

```js
function getValue() {
  $("#DivThisPage").load("http://another-page-on-my-site #DivTheOtherPage", function(response, status, xhr){
  var myVal = $('#DivThisPage').val();
  $("#txtValue").val(myVal);
  });
  
}
```